# What is the purpose and duration of this cookie __utmli used by Google Analytics?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

We are researching on the Cookies rendered by GA on our website which are generated on user's machine.

I found the description of almost all cookies from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage

But one cookie in specific is not menitioned anywhere. "__utmli".

Could anyone here please provide some information like description/purpose and duration of this cookie?

Thanks,
Praful Memane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookie is part of the Enhanced Link Attribution feature that (tries to) distinguish clicks on links to the same destination in the in-page analyses.

If I recall correctly it expires pretty quickly (I think 30 seconds or thereabout) and contains the id (if any) of the clicked link (or its parent) to be read on the next page, so in-page analyses can tell where on the page the clicked link was located.

It seems however that this refers to ga.js exclusively, and that the corresponding cookie for analytics.js is called "_gali" as per https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-link-attribution.

Comment: Can you provide a link for this? a really interesting fact

Comment: Nothing from Google itself I am afraid (I have it from a privacy policy that mentions the cookie). However it is actually mentioned in your cookiepedia link. It seems however that this refers to ga.js exclusively, and that the corresponding cookie for analytics.js is called "_gali" as per https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-link-attribution.

Answer (score 2):

This cookie along with some more are used by GA to provide a better user experience and website performance. It is not essential for Analytics to work but it is nice to be there. You can read some more information on the matter on the links below.

- [Cookiepedia](https://cookiepedia.co.uk/cookies/__utmli)
- [Europa.eu](http://ec.europa.eu/environment/life/cookies/index.htm)
- and  [nordicisic](http://www.isicnordic.org/about/privacy-policy/)